# Initialize and modify class variables in derived classes

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance, initialization, polymorphism

I want to initialize a variable class for my `Base` class and modify it only in some children classes.
 
The initialization of this class variable is in the header:

```
class Base{
public:
    Base();
    int a = 1;
```

The header of my derived class is:

```
class ChildA : public Base{
public:
    ChildA ();
    int a = 2;
}
```

## Problem

I tried to run this:

```
Base classe*;
classe = new ChildA();
std::cout << classe->a << std::endl;
```

The problem is that, instead of printing `2` as I expected, it prints `1` (value initialized in my parent class). For other derived classes, I want `classe->a` to still return `1`.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are the results of upcasting - having a base class point to a derived class object.

I highly recommend you read more on the topic, but a simplified picture is that the base class "carries" the whole object (base and derived content), but can access only it's original, own content. This is why you see `a` value from the base class rather than the derived class.

Lippman's C++ Primer has a very comprehensive explanation of upcasting, downcasting, object slicing, and other inheritance-related concepts. This includes implementing virtual functions which give you the functionality to invoke derived class functions through an interface that's common with base.

Answer (score 0):

```
|----------------|-----------------|
| a (for Base)   | a (for ChildA)  |
|----------------|-----------------|
\________________/
 ^
 |_ classe
```

Sorry if my drawing is not that good! As you can see in the above picture, when you create an object of type `ChildA`, this object contains a part for keeping the data members of the base class (i.e. `Base`) and another part for the data members of derived class (i.e. `ChildA`). Considering the fact that you have a pointer to the base class (i.e. `classe`), this pointer only allows you to access the base member variables and methods. So calling `classe->a`, returns the `Base::a` for you, that is 1.

If you change the type of `classe` pointer into `ChildA`, in that case calling `classe->a` will return 2, because it refers to the `a` inside the derived class, i.e. `ChildA::a`.

> For other derived classes, I want classe->a to still return 1. How can
>   I solve this?

If you need in some derived classes to access different `a`s, it is better to have a virtual function in the base class and override the base function if needed:

```
class Base {
public:
   Base() {}
   virtual int getA() { return a; }
private:
   int a = 1;
};

 class ChildA : public Base 
 {
 public:
     ChildA() {}
     int a = 2;
 };

 class ChildB : public Base
 {
 public:
    ChildB() {}
    int getA() { return a; }
 private:
    int a = 2;
 };
```

Now by calling `getA()` on a pointer of `Base` or `ChildA`, you will have 1, but calling `getA` on an object of type `ChildB` will return 2.